# doesn't show ubiquity's welcome screen, directly start desktop where install icon appear

Tags: images, iso-image

In my ubuntu 11.04 customized

doesn't show ubiquity's welcome screen, directly start desktop where install icon appear.

Please help

Comment: please be specific in what you're asking - are you installing it? Running of live cd? Do you have an already installed system?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying it from a USB Live System witout using the recommened "Universal USB installer" or usb-creator-gtk, it is not unexpected.

I make an Ubuntu iso bootable by extracting it's content in a pendrive. Then use `sudo syslinux --install /dev/sdb` to create an mbr. then renaming **isolinux** folder into **syslinux** folder, then booting from the usb. In this case a welcome screen is show.

But if you are trying to boot using grub2, you most probably use this kind of command or entry in `grub.cfg` file

```
root=(hd1,msdos1)  
linux /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --  
initrd /casper/initrd.lz
```

this case you have to put `only-ubiquity` in the `linux` line (2nd line).
so that the line becomes
`linux /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --`

Hope this will help